# External USB hard drive not mounting as expected in macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, data-recovery, fsck

I had this issue with my external 4TB drive in USB docking station that suddenly stopped working on my macOS. I tried connecting it to Windows and Linux machines with same results. I thought the data were lost but today I had some time to solve this and actually recovered 95% of them using only mac's terminal.

Drive had one `extfat` partition on it and when I tried to mount it my mac was saying it was impossible. I don't have the screenshot though.

The disk (and partition) showed up however when running:

```
diskutil list
    /dev/disk3 (external, physical):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk3
       1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
       2:       Microsoft Basic Data                         4.0 TB     disk3s2
```

When I tried to mount it with `mount` I got:

```
sudo mount -t extfat /dev/disk2s2 /Volumes/usb
mount: exec /Library/Filesystems/extfat.fs/Contents/Resources/mount_extfat for /Volumes/usb: No such file or directory
```

diskutil commands yielded somewhat different results:

```
diskutil mount /dev/disk2s2
Volume on disk2s2 failed to mount
If the volume is damaged, try the "readOnly" option
```

I couldn't get them to work or do anymore than that so I decided to go for `fsck` tool; first I tried running it on the entire disk:

```
sudo fsck_exfat -d /dev/disk2
Opening /dev/rdisk2
** Checking volume.
** Checking main boot region.
fsck_exfat: Invalid jump or signature
   Main boot region is invalid.  Trying alternate boot region.
** Checking alternate boot region.
fsck_exfat: Invalid jump or signature
   Alternate boot region is invalid.
** The volume  could not be verified completely.
```

Which didn't actually help but when I ran it on a partition itself with `sudo fsck_exfat -d -y disk3s2` it spew out a veeery large output and found some filesystem errors which It fixed and after that I was able to mount the drive as usual.

When I opened up the drive I found all my directories and files - some of them were however in the folders that they shouldn't be and had o bytes. So that's my actual loss but I dare to say that considering simplicity and how fast this was done - recovering almost everything is a big success.

The question remains - **is there a way to get the rest of the data ?** For the moment I'm planning just to copy the good files to another drive and I can play with this one more.

Comment: I suppose the lesson to be learned from this is not to use non-journaled file systems, because that's what happens to them if there's a sudden disconnect.

Comment: Actualy @KamilMaciorowski raised a valid issue - is there a way to recover the rest of the data ? I will update my "story" :)